# How to Add a row vector to a column vector like matrix multiplication

Tags: matlab, product, vectorization, addition

I have a nx1  vector and a 1xn vector. I want to add them in a special manner like matrix multiplication in an efficient manner (vectorized):

Example:

```ml
A=[1 2 3]'

B=[4 5 6]

A \odd_add B = 
[1+4 1+5 1+6
 2+4 2+5 2+6
 3+4 3+5 3+6
]
```

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html):

```ml
A=[1 2 3]'

B=[4 5 6]

bsxfun(@plus, A, B)
```

The result is

```
ans =

     5     6     7
     6     7     8
     7     8     9
```

Comment: Thank you, I hope the solution to be fast enough.

Comment: As I have tested it, it's about 6 times slower than regular matrix multiplication. I used exp(A) and exp(B) and multiplied them and then retrieved the special summation using log() function. This approach is more faster!! Can your code be vectorized?

Comment: I disagree with your tests; I find `bsxfun` to be many times faster than matrix multiplication, for all sizes of vector that I tested. This should be the case, as the computational complexity of multiplication is super-linear in the number of matrix elements.

Comment: Yes, your answer is theoretically true, but the final speed depends on the implementation. You can redo my test in your machine as below: tic; eA= exp(A); eB = exp(B); result = log(eA*eB); toc;

Comment: @remo: How large where the matrices you did the speed tests with? I have the impression that `bsxfun` outperforms your alternative approach for large matrices (I tested with A and B having 1000 elements each).

Comment: I have tested it on a 1000x1000 matrix!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `repmat` function (replicate matrices):

```
repmat(A,1,3)+repmat(B,3,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

From R2016b you can simply do:

```
A=[1 2 3]'

B=[4 5 6]

A+B

ans =

     5     6     7
     6     7     8
     7     8     9
```

Matlab will silently expand both vectors and do the element wise sum. This feature has not been without it's controversy. You can check the details here:

[Matlab expands arithmetic](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/)